# Can't install R package from bioconductor

Tags: r, installation, bioconductor

I am trying to install [RTCGA package from bioconductor](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/RTCGA.html) but when I follow the install instruction:

```
## try http if https is not available
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("RTCGA")
```

I get such an error. Does anyone know how to overcome this issue?

```
> source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
Bioconductor version 3.1 (BiocInstaller 1.18.5), ?biocLite for help
A newer version of Bioconductor is available for this version of R, ?BiocUpgrade for
  help
> biocLite("RTCGA")
BioC_mirror: http://bioconductor.org
Using Bioconductor version 3.1 (BiocInstaller 1.18.5), R version 3.2.2.
Installing package(s) ‘RTCGA’
Warning message:
package ‘RTCGA’ is not available (for R version 3.2.2)
```

Comment: did you try after `biocLite("BiocUpgrade")`

Comment: Ye it worked :P Thanks. You can post it as an answer

Comment: How should I know that I should run `BiocUpgrade`?

Comment: When you tried to use `source` it gives a message `... ?BiocUpgrade for
  help`. So when i looked at `??BiocUpgrade` it told what to do.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I must have been tired, perhaps that's why I haven't noticed that :)

Comment: @user20650 would you like to post your comment as an answer?

Comment: Please feel free to write it up Marcin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @user20650 suggested one should use devel version of bioconductor in that situation since this package haven't been published to release branch yet

```
biocLite("BiocUpgrade")
```